# Query Activity for suscribers that opened campaigns

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, query, sql, activity

We want to get a Data Extension with only de emails of subscribers that opened certain JobIDs.
I ran this SQL Activity but the targeted Data Extension shows 0 records after it finished running.

What could be wrong?

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.SubscriberKey 
FROM _Sent s

WHERE

s.JobID = 222861 OR 
s.JobID = 222863 OR 
s.JobID = 222865 OR 
s.JobID = 222868 OR 
s.JobID = 222869 OR 
s.JobID = 222870 OR 
s.JobID = 222871 OR 
s.JobID = 222872 OR 
s.JobID = 222875 OR 
s.JobID = 222878 OR 
s.JobID = 222889 OR 
s.JobID = 222891 OR 
s.JobID = 222893 OR 
s.JobID = 222894 OR 
s.JobID = 222895 OR 
s.JobID = 222896 OR 
s.JobID = 222898 OR 
s.JobID = 222899 OR 
s.JobID = 223022 OR 
s.JobID = 223023 OR 
s.JobID = 223024 OR 
s.JobID = 223025 OR 
s.JobID = 223026 OR 
s.JobID = 223027

and s.SubscriberKey IN ( 
SELECT o.SubscriberKey 
FROM _Open o
WHERE o.JobID = s.JobID 
AND 
o.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey 
)
```

Comment: @AdamSpriggs answer is correct, but likely the issue on your original query was all the OR statements followed by an AND. You would likely need to nest them like: `(s.JobID = .... OR s.JobID = ..) AND s.SubscriberKey IN(` to provide logic as you initially intended. https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/and_or.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to query the `_Sent` data view.  Since the `JobID` is part of the `_Open` data view, you can simplify it like this:

```
SELECT distinct
o.SubscriberKey
from _Open o
where o.jobid in (
  222861
, 222863
, 222865
, 222868
, 222869
, 222870
, 222871
, 222872
, 222875
, 222878
, 222889
, 222891
, 222893
, 222894
, 222895
, 222896
, 222898
, 222899
, 223022
, 223023
, 223024
, 223025
, 223026
, 223027
)
and o.isunique = 1
```

The `o.isUnique = 1` effectively collapses multiple opens into one row per subscriber.

Comment: Hi this worked great!

The thing with the previous code is that it takes more than an hour and a half to finish running.  An automation query will time-out after 30 minutes if it has not completed.  As I was joining two system data views this causes the system to sort through huge amounts of data.  

Thanks a lot for your contribution!